# Getting sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError with exception value of 'cursor.execute(statement, parameters)' when using Pandas to_sql

Tags: pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift

I am getting the below exception when writing my Pandas dataframe to Redshift using Pandas's `to_sql` method:

Exception type:

```
<class 'sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError'>
```

Exception traceback:

```
MY-PATH/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 717, in do_execute
```

Exception value:

```
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
```

Code:

```
dataframe.to_sql(TABLE-NAME, DB-CONNECTOR, schema='warehouse', method='multi', chunksize=5000, index=False, if_exists='append')
```

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, the issue was in my SQL DDL, where one of my columns had a constraint of `not null` but some of the values in that column that were being written to the data table were null. This was NOT intuitive in the error handling, but wanted to call this out in case others were using the `to_sql` pandas method to create/update a data table.